# Eigen Allocator causing Trouble in Templated Class

Tags: c++, std, eigen, templating

I have this class:

```
typedef vector<Eigen::Affine3d,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Affine3d> > VoteList;

template <class T>
class KernelDensityEstimator {

  public:
    KernelDensityEstimator() {}

    void setData(vector<T>& d) {
      data = d;
    }

    void setKernel(double (*k)(T&, T&)) {
      kernel = k;
    }

    double evaluate(T& p) {
      double sum;
      for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        sum += (*kernel)(p, data[i]);
      }
      return sum/data.size();
    }

  private:
    double (*kernel) (T&, T&);
    vector<T> data;

};
```

I want to use with with the type T = Eigen::Affine3d for now. However, when I call `setData()` it's causing me troubles because Eigen requires to specify an Eigen::aligend_allocator for std containers to use with Eigen.

So when I give a `vector<Eigen::Affine3d,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Affine3d> >` (aka `VoteList`) as the input parameter to `setData()` my compiler complaines that:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘VoteList {aka std::vector<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2> > >}’ to ‘std::vector<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2>, std::allocator<Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2> > >&’
```

Which kind of makes sense, but I thought that the allocator is part of the object type. Is there a way around this and keeping my `KernelDensityEstimator` generic?

Comment: Note that you can use `Eigen::aligned_allocator<T>` with any type `T` not only Eigen's types! You can also use other any other aligned allocator, like `boost::aligned_allocator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Eigen's std::vector specializations for the types you are planing to use, as detailed [there](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html#title3), e.g.:

```
#include<Eigen/StdVector>
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Affine3d)
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Matrix4d)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to have a different type for your member `data` depending on the class template parameter type `T`. There are several ways to do that, here is one suggestion:

- Define a special storage type for your class, in which you keep the data (best put it in a suitable namespace or inside your class):

  ```
  //normal storage type
  template<typename T>
  struct storage_type_impl
  {
      using type = std::vector<T>;
  };

  //storage type for Eigen::Transform types
  template<typename ... Args>
  struct storage_type_impl<Eigen::Transform<Args ...> >
  {
      using type = std::vector<Eigen::Transform<Args ...>
                             , Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Transform<Args ...> > >;
  };

  template<typename T>
  using storage_type = typename storage_type_impl<T>::type;
  ```
- Now you can use that inside your class, together with a templated `setData` method (that is sufficient as the compiler will still complain if it cannot perform the data copy/move):

  ```
  template <class T>
  struct KernelDensityEstimator
  {
      template<typename D>
      auto setData(D&& d)
      {
          data = std::forward<D>(d);  //calls move assignment if d is an rvalue
                                      //otherwise a copy is performed
      }
      //...

  private:
      storage_type<T> data;
      //...
  };
  ```

The code is untested as I don't have Eigen available at the moment, but I hope it's still able to explain the basic idea.